# pandas scatterplots: how to make unfilled symbols

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to plot unfilled symbols but the matplotlib facecolors='none' argument just seems to change the fill colour. Note, i am using matplotlib style 'ggplot'.

Original code snippet with filled symbols:

```
ax=df.plot(kind='scatter', x='clay', y='vf1',xlim=[0,0.6],ylim=[0,6.0e-06],
            color='DarkBlue', s=40, label='u*=1, w=0')
```

[image: original, filled contours]

Now attempting to use facecolors='none' (and setting edgecolors to the colour i want them)

```
ax=df.plot(kind='scatter', x='clay', y='vf1',xlim=[0,0.6],ylim=[0,6.0e-06],
            facecolors='none', edgecolors='DarkBlue', s=40, label='u*=1, w=0')
```

[image: attempting to unfill contours]

It turns out that no matter what colour i enter for 'facecolors', the shading is always light blue. Does anybody know what's going on here, and how i can actually get an unshaded symbol?

***UPDATE****
After BrenBarn's answer below, i have the following, which is exactly what i wanted.

```
ax=df.plot(kind='scatter', x='clay', y='vf1',xlim=[0,0.6],ylim=[0,6.0e-06],
            c='none', edgecolor='DarkBlue', s=40, label='u*=1, w=0')
```

[image: perfect!]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It looks like you are not plotting directly with matplotlib, but with pandas (which is using matplotlib under the hood).  But pandas' plot methods take a `c` argument for the point color.  Try passing `c='none'` instead of `facecolor='none'`.